# How to match character inside inline style?

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I want to match one letter or number or symbol inside inline style.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color: #48ad64;font-weight:10px;">hi there</p>
        <div style="background-color: #48ad64;">
            <h3>perfect</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to match any `c` or `o` or `#` or `4` or `;` or `-`

If we take `o` for example, it's supposed to match 5 occurrences.

I want to replace every occurrence within a style declaration using `preg_replace()`.

How can I get this?  I tried so many different expressions, but none of them did what I want.

Some of what I tried:

1. `/(?:\G(?!^)|\bstyle=")(?:.{0,}?)(o)(?=[^>]*>)/`
2. `/(style=")(?:\w+)(o)(([^"]*)")/`

I just need the regex to match all `o` in my HTML. I expect this:

```
<html> 
   <head> 
   </head> 
   <body>
      <p style="c'o'lor: #48ad64;f'o'nt-weight:10px;">how blabla</p> 
      <div style="backgr'o'und-c'o'l'o'r: #48ad64;">
          <h3>perfect normal o moral bla bal</h3> 
      </div> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

I just want all `o` occurrences inside inline-style above to be replaced with `'o'`

Comment: Please clarify your question by posting your expected output when you designate `o` as the target character.  Please include in your question edit, the php code that you have written so that we can fix it.

Comment: @mickmackusa i just need the regex to match all o in my HTML i expect this
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="c`o`l`o` r: #48ad64;f`o`nt-weight:10px;">how blabla</p>
        <div style="backgr`o`und-c`o`l`o`r: #48ad64;">
            <h3>perfect normal o moral bla bal</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
all o in code format above to be matched no more

Comment: Please move your last comment into the question via an Edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick/dirty/simple solution is to use `preg_replace_callback()` with `str_replace()`.

Pattern: ([Demo with Pattern Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/p6bYQh/1)) `/<[^<]+ style="\K.*?(?=">)/`

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b237be4893061fd87a47acd80b21fb11cf2733ce))

```
$html='<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color: #48ad64;font-weight:10px;">hi there</p>
        <div style="background-color: #48ad64;">
            <h3>perfect</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>';

$needle="o";
echo preg_replace_callback('/<[^<]+ style="\K.*?(?=">)/',function($m)use($needle){return str_replace($needle,"<b>$needle</b>",$m[0]);},$html);
//   add the i flag for case-insensitive matching------^                                     ^-- and add i here for case-insensitive replacing
```

Output:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="c<b>o</b>l<b>o</b>r: #48ad64;f<b>o</b>nt-weight:10px;">hi there</p>
        <div style="backgr<b>o</b>und-c<b>o</b>l<b>o</b>r: #48ad64;">
            <h3>perfect</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This is a pure regex replacement method/pattern:

```
$needle="o";
//                                               vv-----------vv--make the needle value literal
echo preg_replace('/(?:\G(?!^)|\bstyle=")[^"]*?\K\Q'.$needle.'\E/',"'$needle'",$html);
//        assumes no escaped " in style--^^^^  ^^-restart fullstring match
```

The `[^"]*?` component eliminates the need for a lookahead.  However, if a font family name (or similar) were to use `\"` (escaped double quotes) then replacement accuracy would be negatively impacted.

I wouldn't call either of these methods "robust" because certain substrings of text may trick the pattern into "over-matching" illegitimate style substrings.

To do this properly, I suggest that you use DomDocument or some other html parser to ensure you are only modifying real/true style attributes.

DomDocument Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uAGKv))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // 2nd params to remove DOCTYPE 
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xp->query('//*[@style]') as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('style',str_replace($needle,"'$needle'",$node->getAttribute('style'))); // no regex
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: thx bro this one really works.
is there is a chance that it matched by regex only?
and can u give me an example to do it with Php Dom 
I need it to match all Tags'inline style is it possible with Php Dom